# How to exclude "type_changes" completely from deep diff as i only care about value changed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, deep-diff

```
from deepdiff import DeepDiff


t1 = {1:1, 2:2, 3:3}
t2 = {1:1, 2:"2", 3:3}
print(DeepDiff(t1, t2), indent=2)
```

Output:

```
{ 'type_changes': { 'root[2]': { 'new_type': <class 'str'>,
                                 'new_value': '2',
                                 'old_type': <class 'int'>,
                                  'old_value': 2
}}}
```

I want is only value changes in my output and exclude 'type_changes'.
I have to compare nested dictionaries and i don't care about type.

Answer (score 2):

From DeepDiff's Documentation: [DeepDiff Docs](https://deepdiff.readthedocs.io/en/latest/diff.html)

**ignore_type_in_groups** -

> Ignore type changes between members of groups of types. For example if
> you want to ignore type changes between float and decimals etc. Note
> that this is a more granular feature.

So in your case, when the old_type is integer and the new_type is a string -

```
print(DeepDiff(t1, t2), indent=2, ignore_type_in_groups=[(int, str)])
```

The output would be -

```
{}
```

Another available option is to convert your DeepDiff object into Dictionary/JSON and control it however you desire.

```
dict = DeepDiff(t1, t2).to_dict()
```